# Move data from one column to another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table **A**

```
col-PK  col2  col3   col4
1       a      aa     aaa
2       b      bb     bbb
```

And a table **B**

```
col-PK  colB  temp   
1       a           
2       b
```

I need to fill in the `temp` column with the `col3` when col2 = colB

**My Attmept**

```
Update B Set temp = (Select A.col3 from A join B where A.col2 = B.colB)
```

but it does not work properly. I get same value for all the rows in `temp`.

**Wrong Output:**

```
 col-PK  colB  temp   
    1       a   aa        
    2       b   aa // it should be `bb`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE B Set temp = (SELECT col3 from A where A.col2 = B.colB)
```

Comment: can you kindly explain what mistake I did. I almost got it. But what did I miss.

Comment: I think if you need to use `join`, check @scaisEdge's answer, you have to get the join result first than `update`, what you did is try to update the column from the `join` result, which is not one to one relationship

Comment: you have to make sure the value return from the `()` is one to one mapping

Comment: in my answer, for each row from B, set `temp` equals to `(SELECT col3 from A where A.col2 = B.colB)`, which could find one and only one (in your case) `col3` from `A` based on that col value in B, back to your query, you are trying to assign the entire join result, which means the '(Select A.col3 from A join B where A.col2 = B.colB) ' does not return only one value based on each row in B.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an uoadte with join

```
 Update B 
 JOIN A on A.col2 = B.colB
 Set B.temp =  A.col3
```